# How to download pygame for non default version of python

Tags: python, pygame

I am running El Capitan, when I type `python --version` the terminal `prints Python 2.7.10`, I have successfully downloaded pygame for Python 2.7.10 but I want to develop in python 3.5.1, I know I can do this by entering `python3` in the terminal, but how do I properly set up pygame for this version of python?

Comment: `pip3 install pygame`? Give that a try.

Comment: Google "pygame os x python 3" resulted in http://florian-berger.de/en/articles/installing-pygame-for-python-3-on-os-x/

Comment: I have tried that @LauroMoura but when i enter `/usr/local/share/python3/easy_install pip` terminal responds `-bash: /usr/local/share/python3/easy_install: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

Use `python3.5 -mpip install pygame`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-m pip` instead of `-mpip`?